# Extracting text from nifi flowfile and usig it as an argument

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I  have groovy code  like this  and i want to extract the value of  TickSolution and  then use  it as an argument for invoking service , which nifi processors should i use to make this task?

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets 
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import org.apache.nifi.processor.io.StreamCallback
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.GregorianCalendar

def flowfile = session.get()
if(!flowfile) return
def date=flowfile.getAttribute('fromDate')
 SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
  def d=new Date(format.parse(date).getTime());
  def newdate=new GregorianCalendar(d.getYear(),d.getMonth(),d.getDay() )
 def TICKS_AT_EPOCH = 621355968000000000;
 def TICKS_PER_MILLISECOND= 10000;
  def TickSolution=(newdate.getTimeInMillis() - TICKS_AT_EPOCH) / TICKS_PER_MILLISECOND

flowfile = session.putAttribute(flowfile, 'filename','Info'+'_'+date)
session.transfer(flowfile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

Comment: you have to use ExecuteScript processor.

Comment: I  wrote this groovy code inside it

Comment: i need to use one more  what  do you mean?

Comment: NiFi having an ExecuteScript processor in which can runs groovy script.

Comment: i run this code(i have typed in my  question) inside executescript processor and it doesn't trows exception but now i wan't to extract value  of TickSolution do you know  how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sally,

You can try below code to process value of TickSolution.

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets 
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import org.apache.nifi.processor.io.StreamCallback
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.GregorianCalendar

def flowfile = session.get()
if(!flowfile) return
def date=flowfile.getAttribute('fromDate')
 SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
  def d=new Date(format.parse(date).getTime());
  def newdate=new GregorianCalendar(d.getYear(),d.getMonth(),d.getDay() )
 def TICKS_AT_EPOCH = 621355968000000000;
 def TICKS_PER_MILLISECOND= 10000;
  def TickSolution=(newdate.getTimeInMillis() - TICKS_AT_EPOCH) / TICKS_PER_MILLISECOND

flowfile = session.putAttribute(flowfile, 'filename','Info'+'_'+date)
flowfile=session.putAttribute(flowfile,'TickSolution',TickSolution)
session.transfer(flowfile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

please let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: Welcome sally.If answer worked for you then feel free to accept as answer it may helpful for someone.